# For any $n \times n$ matrix $\rm A$, is there an $n \times n$ matrix $\rm B$ such that $\rm B^2 = A$?

Tags: matrices

Does there exist a matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$ for any $n \times n$  matrix $A$ ?

Comment: If you are working over $\mathbb C$ and $A$ is invertible, then yes.  Otherwise, things can get complicated.  But to give an example of something with no square root, let $A$ be the $2\times 2$ matrix with a 1 in the top right and zeros everywhere else.  This squares to zero, so if $B^2=A$, then $B^4=0$, but since $B$ is $2\times 2$, this implies that $B^2=0$.

Comment: If you are not using complex numbers, the easiest counter example is $n=1$ and $A=-1$

Comment: @Andrei I'm not using complex numbers but $\Bbb F_5$. So why is that a counter example? ;)

Comment: $A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ is a counterexample over any field.

Comment: I have to confess I was going to give Andrei's example myself, but I'd probably have said "If you're working over the reals, then ..." and never had had the "aha" that Hagen's answer gave me. :)  So... thanks to both Andrei and Hagen!

Comment: but i can't understand how B^4 = 0 implies that B^2 = 0. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B  \\
C & D\\
\end{array}
\right]}=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\sqrt{A-\frac{BC}{A+D \pm 2 \sqrt{AD-BC}} } & \frac{B}{\sqrt{A+D \pm 2 \sqrt{AD-BC}}}   \\
\frac{C}{\sqrt{A+D \pm 2 \sqrt{AD-BC}}} & \sqrt{D-\frac{BC}{A+D \pm 2 \sqrt{AD-BC}} } \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

In the $2$ by $2$ case, provided $A+D \neq \pm 2 \sqrt{AD-BC}$.

Comment: $kId$ satisfies the condition and it has a square root, so a square root exists as soon as a matrix is diagonalizable